# MVP - Who creates new models?

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, mvp

I'm trying to implement MVP into my current project (Webforms) and it's confusing me beyond words.

Let's say that I have a page where I want the user to input his payment information and then send that to the payment processing logic in my application.

So let's say the payment information looks something like this:

```
public class PaymentInformation
{
    public BillingInformation BillingInformation { get; set; }
    public CreditCard CreditCard { get; set; }
}

public class BillingInformation
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class CreditCard
{
    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    public string CVV { get; set; }
    public int ExpirationMonth { get; set; }
    public int ExpirationYear { get; set; }
}
```

Should the View do something like this?

```
public interface IPaymentView
{
    string FirstName { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
    string Address { get; }
    string City { get; }
    string CardNumber { get; }
    string CVV { get; }
    int ExpirationMonth { get; }
    int ExpirationYear { get; }
}
```

and then have the Presenter take all of these properties and create the actual PaymentInformation instance?

Or should the View do this?

```
public interface IPaymentView
{
    PaymentInformation PaymentInformation { get; }
}
```

and in this case the View would take the information from its own controls and create the actual instance of payment information so that the Presenter can use that?

I'm really confused as to how the Presenter is supposed to get "complex" data from the View.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, in MVP, the Presenter is the only class that does any real "thinking".

The view is just a way to interact with the user; to show information to the user, and for the user to input information.

The model is what takes the information and passes it to wherever it need to be, or rather, the presenter tells it to get the information, and pass it. All the model does is store the data.

From what I can see it looks like your view is trying to be your model, and all your view should really do is have a `btnSave_Click(..)` method, which then calls the Presenter to run an appropriate method to store/show payment information, which then tells the model to get from the view/set to the view.

So to summarize;

1. The Model and the View are basic classes that do no thinking at all.
2. The Model just holds information to get/set.
3. The View just shows information for the user.
4. The Presenter is the brains of the operation. It tells who; what to do; and when.

Comment: and to answer your question more specifically: the Presenter does.